# Will `typedef enum {} t` allow scoped enum element identifiers in C++0x?

Tags: c++, enums, c++11

I believe the new C++ standard allows for an extra "scope" for enumerated types:

```
enum E { e1, e2 };

E var = E::e1;
```

Since I know lots of source files containing the old C-style enum typedef, I wondered if the new standard would allow using the typedef for these otherwise anonymous enumerated types:

```
typedef enum { d1, d2 } D;
D var = D::d1; // error?
```

Comment: I'd guess that `D` defined with a typedef is for practical purposes equivalent to a proper `enum D { }` and so the same rules apply to both. So no, that shouldn't be an error in C++0x.

Comment: +1 for finally calling it C++1x :)

Comment: I prefer C++0x because that's the term Stroustroup himself uses.

Comment: Wasn't X for the roman symbol? -- anyway, usually the standard committee is quite careful not to introduce 'breaking' changes. You can expect all valid c++ code in c++03 to still be valid in c++0x,1x.. whatever.

Comment: It's not about breaking changes; it's about What I have to do to existing enum declarations in order to use the mentioned extensions.

Comment: @Manuel: Stroustroup also uses "1x" in the document dribeas mentioned.

Comment: @xtofl - Yes but he distinguishes C++0x (the one about to be accepted) and C++1x (the one that will come afterwards)

Comment: @Manuel: And C++1x will in turn become C++2x. Perhaps better if C++0x would be called C++ 2.0, C++98 for C++ 1.0, and C++2003 for C++ 1.1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The new standard will add a new type of strong enum, but the syntax will be slightly different, and old style enums will be compatible (valid code in C++03 will be valid C++0x code) so you will not need to do anything to keep legacy code valid (not the typedef, not anything else).

```
enum class E { e1, e2 }; // new syntax, use E::e1
enum E2 { e1, e2 }; // old syntax, use e1 or E2::e1 (extension)
```

There is a C++ FAQ [here](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#enum) that deals with this particular issue.

Comment: I think the OP knows the typedef is not necessary, he's just concerned about legacy C code that uses it.

Comment: Legacy code will use the old style enums, and those enums (the one in the OP) will bring the names into the enclosing scope. I am editing the answer so that it is clearer.